# Getting the entries of a ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, many-to-many

I'm working with a ManyToManyField and using a ModelMultipleChoice on form, I want to get the entries, but all I get is `appname.Extra.none`

**models.py**

```
class Extra(models.Model):
    extra_n = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    extra_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.extra_n

class Meal(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    category = models.ForeignKey(MealCategory, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='meal_images/', blank=False)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    extras = models.ManyToManyField(Extra, related_name='extras')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
class MealForm(forms.ModelForm):

    extras = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), queryset=Meal.extras)

    class Meta:
        model = Meal
        exclude = ("restaurant",)
```

**views.py**

```
 def restaurant_meal(request):
    meals = Meal.objects.filter(restaurant = request.user.restaurant).order_by("-id")
    return render(request, 'restaurant/meal.html', {"meals": meals})
```

**The output desired is getting the extras added displayed on restaurant_meal view.**

Answer (score 0):

you can try change

```
meals = Meal.objects.filter(restaurant = request.user.restaurant).order_by("-id")
```

to

```
meals = Meal.objects.filter(restaurant = request.user.restaurant).prefetch_related('extras').order_by("-id")
```

and try again.

Doc of this in [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)